# when is てます used over ています if you are supposed to be talking "polite"

Tags: politeness

I understand that てる and てます are basically shortened versions of ている and ています, but if you are supposed talking "formally"/"polite" why would you use a shortened version?

Comment: You probably don't avoid the words 'don't' or 'can't' talking to bosses, teacher etc. I imagine?

Comment: Politeness and formality are not the same concept, though they may overlap. It's not strange to speak informally in a polite way.

Comment: when would you speak like this before talking informally/short form

Answer (score 2):

てる and てます are very common and safe in ordinary workplaces when you are *speaking* Japanese. You can even combine it with honorific verbs and say something like 見てらっしゃいます. But they are generally avoided when you are *writing* something formally. Also, when you are giving a formal speech with a microphone in front of dozens of people, it's safer to avoid this contraction even if it's spoken.

In general, you cannot explain an expression's register using a single axis. We need to use different adjectives that are related but different, such as "honorific", "polite", "written", "formal", "stilted" and "pompous". If I have to choose a single adjective to describe てる/てます, I would choose "colloquial", which is related to but not exactly the same as "informal".